# How do I add another sibling element in e4x?

Tags: javascript, e4x

If I want to create:

```
<foo>
  <bar>example1</bar>
  <bar>example2</bar>
</foo>
```

using e4x, and I already have:

```
foo.bar = <bar>example1</bar>
```

How do I add the additional bar tag?

Comment: I just edited my answer: `foo.bar` should be wrong. `foo += ...` is what we need here. E4X is designed to work just like usual JavaScript objects (especially like `Object` literals). So, there really is no big mystery other than the lack of proper documentation (the IBM site is kind of helpful, though).

Comment: Yeah, I'm having to ramp up quickly on this, thought I'd ping SO about it ;-) The actual ecma spec isn't entirely shoddy either, though yeah, documentation is a little thin on the ground.

Comment: If you are talking about the *white paper*: it's a good look-up, but lacks examples imo. Anyhow, if you stick to the general javascript pattern with E4X you should do just fine. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either write another *literal*,

```
foo += <bar>example3</bar> ;
```

or you use the relevant methods: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javascript4x.html (Table-1),

```
var addition = <bar>example3</bar>
foo.insertChildAfter(foo.bar[1],addition) ;
```

HTH

Comment: I tested on rhino JS on the JDK and it should be foo.bar += <bar>example3</bar> ;   It looks like += appends siblings.

Comment: I believe if you have other nodes besides bar inside foo, += will append at the end not after the bar. So for <foo><bar/><baz/></foo> insertChildAfter will do the right job getting <foo><bar/><bar/><baz/></foo> instead of <foo><bar/><baz/><bar/></foo>